# (PHP,MySQL) Adding information from an SQL table to a PHP web page table which has same field id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatables

My English is not so well and  I am new with php. So, maybe you can be bored with my question. I am really sorry for that.

**Here's the Question:**
*I have a table created in SQL database like this:*

```
-   ID       Name        PICTURE
 -   1       John        john.jpg
 -   1       dora        h.jpg
 -   1       Dane        hkjpg
 -   2       Mougli      f.jpg
 -   3       Mona        g.jpg
```

*and I want to show the data in a table created in my web page like this:*

```
-   ID       Name        PICTURE
 -   1       John        john.jpg
 -   1       dora        h.jpg
 -   1       Dane        hkjpg
```

I Want to show all the information in my web page which has the id "1" and others will not be in the table. I want to use a loop to do that. If you know how to do that then please try to answer with the full php code( I mean the code should start from connecting database to the page and end to looping the information in the table.
 Of-course it depends on you if you want to write the full code. But it would be very helpful for me).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a strict sense, that's not really a table; it has no PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php
You want to start with the __construct and query functions. 
Query will return a PDOStatement object that you can fetch.
Your code should look like this:

```
// Connect
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

// Query
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ID = 1");

// Fetch
$data = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['ID'].', '.$row['name'].', '.$row['PICTURE']."<br />\n";
}
```